# Wordpress Query not Working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use this code to pull out posts that have the PackageID 3, however it just doesn't seem to work and pulls out any post instead.

What am I missing?

```
        <?php 
        $args = array(
            'orderby'  => 'rand',
            'order'    => 'ASC',    

            'meta_query' => array(
                'key' => 'packageID',
                'value' => '3',
                'compare' => '=',
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
        );
        query_posts($args); ?>
        <?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: check if your host have disabled orderby rand - I know that WPengine does that by default since it can give slow queries.

Comment: is this your full code? after the while loop are echo anything?

Comment: Yes sorry there is however just removed to save having a long post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because the meta_query needs to be an array inside an array, so the code would look like

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'orderby'  => 'rand',
        'order'    => 'ASC',    

        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'packageID',
                'value' => '3',
                'compare' => '=',
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            )
        ),
    );
    query_posts($args); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Id say use WP_Query when you need multiple loops, or complex loops, query_posts() when you need to modify the current loop and get_posts() I haven't really ever used to be honest but WordPress says the most appropriate use for get_posts is to create an array of posts based on a set of parameters. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/